# Google Chrome wouldn't save password for Gmail only

Tags: browser

Google Chrome is quick, works for lots of websites. But I found out that it would not save my password when I log into Gmail!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because Gmail uses javascript to redirect the page very quickly, we may not have the chance to  click "Save Password" on Gmail. Instead, try visiting [accounts.google.com](http://accounts.google.com). Login there and you'd be able to save your password. Of course, saving it there would mean you can use it when  logging into Gmail.

Comment: This solution does not work anymore.

Answer (score 7):

If you are signed into Chrome with same account, Chrome won’t ask to save the password. Following these steps you can force Chrome to ask "save password" again:

1. In chrome > Settings > **Disconnect** your Google Account.
2. **Log off** all gmail sessions that you could have open.
3. Go to gmail login page.
4. Type login and password (with @gmail.com recommended) and google will ask you for save it again!
5. In chrome > Settings > Sign in to Chrome.
6. Allow Chrome to sync the data (bookmarks, passwords...)

And that's it!
Enjoy!

I've found the solution in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bvb1lK1Felo

Comment: It isn't fully clear how this answer addresses the author's question.

Comment: @Ramhound If you are signed into Chrome with same account, Chrome won’t ask to save the password. It’s said in the video linked (the source of this steps).

Comment: As of April 2020, this solution still works.

Answer (score 3):

I've just solved the problem by doing:

**Passwords** > **Google account** > **Password Options**

Then, export your passwords to a CSV format. Open the file, remove everything other than the header and add your credentials to it. Then, import the CSV file and your Gmail password will be there.

Comment: This doesn't address the poster's problem. Export only exports passwords that are already saved. The question was how to save the password in the first place.

Comment: @RobertM.: "remove everything other than the header and add your credentials to it. Then, import the CSV file" worked for me

Comment: @Greg My bad, I get it now. It works.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the latest solution on Google Official
https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/10500247?hl=en. Just add those passwords in CSV which are to be imported.
Moreover for format, you can Export Current passwords and delete everything except header, now add desired password. After this upload CSV as specified in the link above.

Comment: This should be the top reply. It's the only solution that works as of January 2022.

Answer (score 2):

For the past few years Chrome has not offered to save Google passwords no matter what I've done.  I believe this is because they are pushing users to use profiles and turn on "Allow Chrome sign-in".

*Please note, this problem is specific only to Google sites and my passwords are saving fine on every other domain*.

My solution was to simply open the password manager and click "Add" to add them manually, using "accounts.google.com" as the domain. This may be a cumbersome solution for some but for me there there are only a couple so it was easy enough.

Comment: Phew, this worked for me after various other methods failed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check in your browser that when it wants to save your password you choose correct answer:**"Save this Password"**

in `Setting` search *`password`* and find this `option`:

```
Offer to save passwords I enter on the web
```

Comment: The browser offers to save, but doesn't save the password until one actually clicks on the little pop-up button. As the other person said, Gmail is very fast, so the particular problem occurs.

Comment: even with this option checked off, you'll still not be able to save password in Gmail

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays the only solution is to add it manually.
In chrome enter settings -> Autofill -> Password manager
Under Saved passwords, click "Add".

In website enter `accounts.google.com`.

In user name enter your full google account email adress.

In password enter your password.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem. It's very simple, you cannot use your Google Password for GMail because you are logged out of all Google services, including your Google Password Manager.

To solve this, save the Google password on your local machine.

Google Password Manager > Add Password > "Save only on this device" (instead of "Save in your Google Account"