# Google Chrome not prompting for password save on Google sites as of now apparently

Tags: google-chrome, password-management

I'm trying to save my Gmail (or Google) account password to the browser, but it seems to not be allowed anymore recently. I remember I could do this if I was not signed into a Google "profile", such as answered here:

[Google Chrome wouldn't save password for Gmail only](https://superuser.com/questions/523555/google-chrome-wouldnt-save-password-for-gmail-only)

However, I just now tried all of the answers, wasn't logged into a profile when submitting the Gmail password, and was given no prompt to save the password. I was given a prompt to create a profile however, which I declined.

I tried again by completely signing out of the Google account, signing out of the Chrome account, deleting the profile from the profile manager (by clicking my avatar to the right of the Chrome address/URL/search bar and star bookmark button), and then creating a new profile and skipping the sync prompts, then by going into Settings and clicking "You and Google" (on the left) then "Sync and Google services" > "Other Google services" then disabling "Allow Chrome sign-in", clicking the Relaunch prompt at the bottom left of the browser (which restarted all of my profile sessions)... then went to gmail.com, logged in with my username and password, skipping/declining the Chrome sync prompts all the way (and it showed that it didn't log in there), got to my Gmail, but no password prompt to save at all.

The password prompt works on other sites, non-Google sites, and "Offer to save passwords" was already enabled.

I'm flummoxed; I'm not sure what the secret trick is now to save my Gmail/Google account password in a Chrome browser session or profile, but it would be really nice to know if possible because I prefer to save long hard-to-remember passwords for security reasons, and I don't let others get into my computer or phone (though I remember hard-to-figure out passwords or biometrics for those logins). If Google is just blocking this completely in Chrome, maybe I should switch to Brave or Firefox. I'm still holding out belief that there's a solution, and their docs don't mention whether this still is allowed/possible or not.